# using gsutil to move file from bucket to instance: "Failure: Cannot serialize credentials for GCE service accounts.."

Tags: linux, ssh, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to move a file from a bucket to an instance in GCP (Google Cloud Platform). I'm in the cloud console > Compute Engine > VM instances > click the SSH button under the Connect column for the instance in the list. I now have an SSH window open and I run:

`# gsutil cp gs://cc-test1/test.txt /tmp`

Where `gs://cc-test1` is my bucket and `text.txt` is the file I want to move to the instance I am SSH'd into and put it in directory `/tmp`.

I get error:
INFO 1220 14:38:06.447719 transport.py] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
Failure: Cannot serialize credentials for GCE service accounts..

The instance is Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

`# gsutil config`

Copy the link that is in the output and paste it into a browser.

Copy the authorization code that appears.

Paste that to authorization code into the ssh session after:
`Enter the authorization code:`

Rerun your gutil command in the ssh session.

PS - hoping there is a less laborious solution.